# How can i extract lat and long values from string?

Tags: javascript

For example,

```
'POINT (-109.42948819496439 44.5177967942721)'
```

how would I extract the lat and long values from the preceding string?

I tried:

```
coords.substring(7,14) + ' ' + coords.substring(15,22)
```

But I don't think I can rely on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the format is always the same, you can do this with [`substring()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp):

```js
var x = 'POINT (-109.42948819496439 44.5177967942721)';

var lat = x.substring(x.indexOf('(') + 1, x.lastIndexOf(' '));
var lon = x.substring(x.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1, x.indexOf(')'));

console.log(lat);
console.log(lon);
```

But the best alternative for manipulating patterns in strings is **regex**.

Answer (score 6):

```js
// Robust matching of two space-separated floats within parentheses:
let point = 'POINT (-109.42948819496439 44.5177967942721)';
let [, lat, long] = point.match(/\(([+-]?[0-9.]+) ([+-]?[0-9.]+)\)/);

console.log(lat, long);
```

Note: [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) is only as robust as the provided test-cases guarantee. Throws a `TypeError` if pattern doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = 'POINT (-109.42948819496439 44.5177967942721)';
var res = input.replace("POINT ", "");
var res1 = res.replace(")", "");
var res2 = res1.replace("(", "");
var fields = res2.split(' ');

var lat = fields[0];
var long = fields[1];
```

Comment: You should explain what this code is doing, and why it's more reliable than the method using substrings.